# Jmeter script for different orderlines

Tags: jmeter

I have question on jmeter

we have different types of order lines like (3 ,5, 15) orders.
i need to create a script for different order lines.

please find the my approach in loadrunner, how can we do the same in jmeter

In loadrunner--> I have created different action with switch case
**Action name :**

```
OrderLine(trans, int orderline) 
        {
        switch case
        case 3:
                requests for 3 order lines
        case 5:
                requests for 5 order lines
        case 15:
                requests for 15 order lines; break;
        }
```

in another action, i will call OrderLine transaction

```
Action_03Lines()
{
Orderlines(OrderLines_03,3);
Orderlines(OrderLines_03,3);
Orderlines(OrderLines_03,3);
}

Action_05Lines()
{
Orderlines(OrderLines_05,5);
Orderlines(OrderLines_05,5);
Orderlines(OrderLines_05,5);
Orderlines(OrderLines_05,5);
Orderlines(OrderLines_05,5);
}
```

and i will call the actions on %ile bases.. like Action_03lines will run for 90% and Action_05 & Action_15 will execute with 5% each.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Switch_Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) as parent of each request with relevant number in switch value

> Switch Value
>   The number (or name) of the subordinate element to be invoked.

Comment: How can we pass parameter in jmeter transaction. if you see my above example in Loadrunner i passed same transaction with different parameters. similarly can i use the jmeter transaction to use different parameters

Answer (score 0):

In JMeter you have:

1. [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#test_fragments) - to hold the reusable code
2. [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) - to refer the reusable code blocks where required
3. [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) or [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)  - to iterate the block of code for desired number of times or while certain condition is (not) met

Comment: how to send orderline data like 3,5 in the transaction in module controller. i looking for transaction name with orderline should be passed by action to call module controller.

Comment: can you please help me with above issue. how to call the transaction with different values.